# Get CAPTCHA every time when I'm on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, captcha

This is related to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13002/im-not-human-if-im-using-my-mobile) but not the same.

I've posted questions on SE sites before on 
my mobile, but I noticed that these past few days I need to verify about 100% of the time.

Unlike the linked question I'm using iPhone 4, which should be able to handle JavaScript. I've used SE with my iPhone 3G but don't post answers enough to know if this is just a recent problem or if it came with the switch of phone which happened not too long ago.

Note: got hit again asking this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an issue with our hiding of the WMD editor for mobile devices.

A fix will be pushed this evening.